# ArgumentParser: exclusive groups not enforced when using some argument options

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default=True, const=True)
group.add_argument('--bar', dest='foo', action='store_false')
parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar']) # no error
```

I am a bit confused that the code above does not produce any error despite the fact that `--foo` and `--bar` should be exclusive. Is this the expected behavior? Or should we not mess around with argument options in exclusive groups?

Note that when `default=True` is not passed as an argument to`--foo`, the expected error occurs.

I observed this behavior in Python 2.7.13 as well as 3.5.3.

Comment: The nargs? could be messing with the test.  A positional in a group has to have that  args, and gets special handling. I'd have to study the code.  What if const set a different value.?  And if `bar` had a different dest?

Comment: Why is `const` same as `default`?  It looses all the benefits of setting nargs=?.

Comment: This is just an MCV example of a problem. It does not do anything meaningful. My question is more a language-grammar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is buried in `take_action`:

```
        argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)

        # error if this argument is not allowed with other previously
        # seen arguments, assuming that actions that use the default
        # value don't really count as "present"
        if argument_values is not action.default:
            seen_non_default_actions.add(action)
            for conflict_action in action_conflicts.get(action, []):
                if conflict_action in seen_non_default_actions:
                    msg = _('not allowed with argument %s')
                    action_name = _get_action_name(conflict_action)
                    raise ArgumentError(action, msg % action_name)
```

and specifically that `'argument_values is not action.default'` test.

Optional positionals (`nargs='?'`) are always 'seen`, in the sense that an empty list satisfies its`nargs`.  In that case it gets the`action.default`value.  That's handled by a special case in`_get_values()`.

But for mutually-exclusive testing we don't want those actions to be 'seen', hence this extra test to set the 'seen_non_default_actions` set.

The `is` test is pretty restrictive.  The items have to have the same `id`.

Your example is failing because the `True` in `const=True` has the same id as in `default=True`.

`parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])` sets `foo` to the `const`.  But because it matches the `default` it is not-seen, and doesn't trigger the exclusive error.

Normally `const` and `default` will have different values, taking advantage to the 3-way parsing of '?'.

This `is not` test has failed in another case.  Numbers less than 256 are unique.  More on this at http://bugs.python.org/issue18943

---

test case:

```
In [1]: import argparse
   ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
   ...: a1=group.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default=True, const=True)
   ...: a2=group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
   ...: 
In [2]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
Out[2]: Namespace(bar=False, foo=True)      # the True's match
```

change `const`:

```
In [3]: a1.const
Out[3]: True
In [4]: a1.const='other'
In [5]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO] | --bar]
ipython3: error: argument --bar: not allowed with argument --foo
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```

Another case where values match in the `is` sense:

```
In [6]: a1.const=None;a1.default=None
In [7]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
Out[7]: Namespace(bar=False, foo=None)
```

and for small numbers:

```
In [8]: a1.const=3;a1.default=3
In [9]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
Out[9]: Namespace(bar=False, foo=3)
```

but not big ones:

```
In [10]: a1.const=300;a1.default=300
In [11]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO] | --bar]
ipython3: error: argument --bar: not allowed with argument --foo
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```

Strings can be tricky.  Literals in the code are unique, but ones created by splitting are not:

```
In [12]: a1.default='test'
In [14]: parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'test', '--bar'])
Out[14]: Namespace(bar=False, foo='test')   # no error
```

This is more like how the commandline provides strings:

```
In [16]: parser.parse_args('--foo test --bar'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO] | --bar]
ipython3: error: argument --bar: not allowed with argument --foo
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```